# How do I use multiple copy commands in Grunt Build?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I would like to copy some files, run other tasks, and then again copy some files:

```
copy:{....},
concat:{...},
copy:{...}
```

However, I get the following error when I run my grunt build:

```
SyntaxError: Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode
```

Of course I understand, that I cannot use the same property (i.e. "copy") multiple times in the grunt json. But what is the solution to my problem? How can I copy at different positions of the gruntfile.js?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split your `copy` comment in the desired subtasks:

```
copy: {
    task1: {
        files: [...]
    }
    task2: {
        files: [...]
    },
    task3: {
        files: [...]
    }
}
```

And then run Grunt like that:

```
grunt.registerTask('development', [ 'copy:task1', 'concat', 'copy:task2' ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do the same job like this. Here is my task, right at the end of the Gruntfile:

```
grunt.registerTask('client', [
    'concat:app_js',
    'concat:lib_js',
    'uglify:app_lib_js',
    'concat:client_js',
    'concat:client_css',
    'includes',
    'concat:client_html',
    'copy:client_gfx',
    'copy:client_xml'
]);
```

This is referencing a structure higher up that looks like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: { ... concat jobs here ... },

    // This is how to have multiple copy jobs
    copy: {
        client_gfx: {
            // spec here
        },
        client_xml: {
            // spec here
        }
    }
}
}
```